# Live search: Not Sending javascript greek parameters to php

Tags: javascript, php, search, parameters, live

I have a live search box which is searching from a database using english character. Everything is fine until this point.When I'm trying to search using GREEK characters (etc κοσμημα) my search box fries. Nothing happens. I dont know what is the problem and i need your help.

Here is my javascript code. i can alert the str given as parameter GREEK or ENGLISH until the last line of the javascript code.Then i can not handle it in my php file for some reason. It disappears like never typed in the search box.

When i alert(str); everything its ok, but when I'm trying to print the text sended from javascript in the live_search.php (php file) nothing shows up. With the english characters i have the results.

```
function showResult(str) {

  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px dotted #A5ACB2";
      document.getElementById("hide_for_search").style.visibility="hidden";
     }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","live_search.php?q="+ str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();  
}
```

[image: Live search ΕΝGLISH WORKING]

[image: Live search GREEK NOT WORKING]

Comment: why are you doing uri **DECODE** on your search string? `str = uriencode(); str = uridecode(str)` is rather pointless

Comment: I know that this just a testing code...Do you have any idea why i can only search only with english and not with greek(κοσμ..)?

Comment: i also get this error when im trying to search using greek charachters  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: uri_dec is not set anywhere in your function?

Comment: @ois: op had them in there, and then removed the line defining that var.

Comment: @MarcB well ATM that is the obvious error.

Comment: im getting 403 : Forbidden